# Default Monolog messages with Silex

Tags: silex, monolog

I'm using Silex 1.1 and Monolog 1.0.0. My code and my problem:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\MonologServiceProvider(), array(
  'monolog.name' => 'myname',
  'monolog.logfile' => ROOT . '/logs/log.txt',
  'monolog.level'   => Monolog\Logger::INFO
));

. . .
$app['monolog']->addInfo('xxx');
```

Everything works fine, but I get default messages like these:

```
[2013-12-13 00:20:56] myname.INFO: Matched route "GET_api_v1_predictions" (parameters: "_controller": "predictions.controller:index", "_route": "GET_api_v1_predictions") [] []
[2013-12-13 00:20:56] myname.INFO: > GET /api/v1/predictions [] []
```

How I can disable them?
(If I change the logging level to WARNING and use addWarning then just my messages are displayed, but I want to use the INFO level).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still create a logger for your application which is not used by other processes:

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// initialize the logger
$app['mylog'] = $app->share(function($app) {
   return new Logger('mylog');
});
$app['mylog']->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('/logfile/mylog.log', Logger::INFO));
$app['mylog']->addInfo('Private Log initialized');
```

Comment: It's worth noting that you *must* use a name other than `$app['monolog']` for your service otherwise Silex will still use it, even if `MonologServiceProvider` isn't registered in your app.

Answer (score 1):

Currently [there's no way to disable them](https://github.com/fabpot/Silex/blob/master/src/Silex/Provider/MonologServiceProvider.php), the log commands are registered unconditionally.

The short-term solution is to copy MonologServiceProvider into your own app, change the log commands as you need.

The long-term solution is to fork the silex repository, change the MonologServiceProvider to provide a way to disable those commands, then create a pull request so everyone can enjoy your work.